# How can we say that DF = BE =1?

Tags: geometry

If ABCD is a square with each equal side 1 , AFC is a arc of circle centered at D and AEC is a arc of circle centered at B. How can we say that DF = BE =1?[image]

It is clear that the radius of the both arc is equal and even the angle. I can write that the area of the two arc will be equal  but why  DF = BE =1?

Answer (score 1):

$F$ lies on the circle with the center at $D$, and so does $C$, meaning that the distance from $D$ to $C$ is equal to the distance from $D$ to $F$.

Same thing with $B$.